# vb.net to mono -stack overflow

Tags: vb.net, mono

i am converting my existing .net 2 project written in vb.net to mono

i am getting the below issue , what can cause this ? and where to look at ?

```
vbnc : Command line : error VBNC99999: Unexpected error: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
  at Mono.Cecil.SignatureWriter.WriteCustomAttributeFieldOrPropType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00001] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-mono-basic-a74642a/vbnc/cecil/Mono.Cecil/AssemblyWriter.cs:2348 
  at Mono.Cecil.SignatureWriter.WriteCustomAttributeElement (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type, CustomAttributeArgument argument) [0x00035] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-mono-basic-a74642a/vbnc/cecil/Mono.Cecil/AssemblyWriter.cs:2261 
  at Mono.Cecil.SignatureWriter.WriteCustomAttributeElement (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type, CustomAttributeArgument argument) [0x00043] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-mono-basic-a74642a/vbnc/cecil/Mono.Cecil/AssemblyWriter.cs:2262 
  at Mono.Cecil.SignatureWriter.WriteCustomAttributeElement (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type, CustomAttributeArgument argument) [0x00043] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-mono-basic-a74642a/vbnc/cecil/Mono.Cecil/AssemblyWriter.cs:2262
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Mono's VB.NET compiler (vbnc).

Please [file a bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Compilers&component=Basic) with a test case (or your entire project if that's easier for you).